# mouseover and resize image of different orientation to div container

Tags: javascript, css

When using mouseover a thumbnail of orientation, the image width and height did not fit exactly into "imax", a Div element.

I use the code in HTML Image:

```
onmouseover='chgImg(this.src)' onmouseout='resImg()'
```

and Javascript and CSS:

```
function chgImg(asd) {
    oim = document.getElementById("im").src;
    return document.getElementById("im").src=asd;
}
function resImg() {
    return document.getElementById("im").src=oim;
}


#imax {
    width:222px;
    height:222px;
}
#im {
    width:222px;
    height:auto; /* <-- this will overlap which is a problem. */
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the loaded images are exactly square, too? Also, do you have an example page, so we can actually see the result? BTW, you shouldn't use a global variable `oim` to store the thumbnail's location, this could cause horrible effects (especially when an extension accidentally uses the same variable name). And what's the use of returning the new location?

Comment: not to worry, I don't use any extension. I wish to be able to load any images bound to div's area (222px x 222px)

Comment: No, you are not, but your visitors may. It's just good practice to not pollute the global scope. Another try: are paddings/margins reset to 0 (at least of `imax` and `im`)? Did you look at Firebug's Layout pane (or a comparable thing in another browser tool)? Or do you have an example page, so we can try?